# Any website sells skins for presentation videos/animations in flash

Tags: flash, animation, video, presentation

I hope this question fits into stackoverflow since it is flash orientated, otherwise thanks for correcting me.

On all these web 2.0 websites i see those nice presentation videos/animations like here:  i search a similar skin [addsocials click on "how it works"](http://addsocials.com/).

it would take maybe 1 or 2 days for me to make such a simple but clean animation video. Are there websites where we can buy or download such skins for fast customization?

the only website i know is activeden but i can't find any animation skins to buy. isn't there a market for such things?

thanks for all affiliate-free suggestions or telling your way how to do it (hiring... where) !

Best regards

Comment: I removed the Flex tag because this doesn't really have anything to do with Flex.

Comment: @JonathanRowny you see how noob i am into this topic. Thanks !

Comment: @anhPham  i search skins for flash since thats all i know regarding this. the linked animation is done in flash as5 according to feedback from this website.

Comment: ok, I retag it. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately only few people joined the conversation with little contribution to a solution.
What i found so far after exploring the web is templatemonster.com -> click "Flash intro templates" -> and click "After effect Intros" (if you are familiar with that programm too) -> hit apply or search

To be honest there i only found 1 animation that i could reuse after heavy customization. I decided to build my own and sacrifice 1 or 2 days work for that. It seems that there is no marketplace yet for such kind of things. Common guys - change that ;)

I will wait 2 days and hoping for better answers.